# How to render IFRAME tags if it is in text editor?

Tags: laravel, tinymce

I am using a tinymce text editor for writing a paragraph. If i include youtube video in IFRAME tags inside a text editor then it doesn't render it in the frontend. Just a plain text of iframe is displayed.

Code

```
{!! $item->display_paragraph !!}
```

output

[image: iframe picture]

So how do i render iframe along with text using text editor.

Comment: You should either be using [pageembed](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/premium/pageembed/) (which is a paid plugin) to add the iframe via the dialog or the [code](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/opensource/code/) plugin (which is free) to add the iframe directly in the HTML source. If you add HTML in TinyMCE directly it will not work because it will be entity encoded

Answer (score 0):

Use the TinyMCE Page Embed plugin: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/premium/pageembed/#usingpageembed

Answer (score -1):

I solved this by using mutator.

```
 public function setDescriptionAttribute($value) 
    {
        $this->attributes['description'] = htmlspecialchars_decode($value);
    }
```